# How do I organize my ZSH code? Multiple methods in single file vs multiple files

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm writing a bunch of functions in ZSH for some purpose, named like X_somename say, which the user will run from the command line. There'll be about 20 of them.

I'm wondering which is a more optimal approach (with respect to code organization, performance etc.) -

1. Put everything in a single file, X.zsh, containing function definitions, each having a name of the form X_somename and then source X.zsh in the .zshrc
2. Create separate files, each having a name like X_somename, and include the folder containing them in the PATH env var

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Normal practice is to define functions, one per file, and place the folder in your `fpath`. You should also mark the functions for auto loading. A function should not be a shell-script (so don't add them to your path but to your `fpath` (function path)).

From http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html

```
fpath=(~/myfuncs $fpath)
autoload myfunc1 myfunc2 ...
```

What I actually do is to:

```
if [[ -d $ZDIR/code ]]; then
   # Autoload shell functions from $ZDIR/code with the executable bit on.
   for func in $ZDIR/code/*(N-.x:t); do
      unhash -f $func 2>/dev/null
      autoload +X $func
   done
fi
```

Just pay attention that there are KSH style functions, where you add `function foo()`, from the page I linked above:

> If the KSH_AUTOLOAD option is set, or the file contains only a simple
>   definition of the function, the file’s contents will be executed. This
>   will normally define the function in question, but may also perform
>   initialization, which is executed in the context of the function
>   execution, and may therefore define local parameters. It is an error
>   if the function is not defined by loading the file.
>
> Otherwise, the function body (with no surrounding ‘funcname() {...}’)
>   is taken to be the complete contents of the file. This form allows the
>   file to be used directly as an executable shell script. If processing
>   of the file results in the function being re-defined, the function
>   itself is not re-executed. To force the shell to perform
>   initialization and then call the function defined, the file should
>   contain initialization code (which will be executed then discarded) in
>   addition to a complete function definition (which will be retained for
>   subsequent calls to the function), and a call to the shell function,
>   including any arguments, at the end.

Comment: If use autoload +x for all your function files.. What's the point of using autoload then? Wouldnt that load the function right away instead of loading on-demand? How would that be better than sourcing a file with all your function definitions?

Comment: sorry if I was confusing. IRRC The `+X` is only necessary for KSH-like functions. With SSDs in practice I don't think there is any performance gains using autoloading. The primary advantage is keeping the code isolated, as well as to allow you to add another function by just copying a file over.